# Sonic weapon used by necromancer -- does air have enough density to transmit power like that?

Tags: technology, raised-by-wolves

I think there are real-life sonic weapons that can kill people but the actual explosions/almost complete disintegration that the necromancer's weapon causes seems unrealistic -- no matter how much power she had to produce the sounds, the vibrations still have to be transmitted. In a vacuum it would not work at all and in a thin atmosphere I would guess they would not be effective.

The white whale apparently could kill a human underwater and humans who have swum near them have been "scanned" and even this is quite painful. I think the power that water transmits would make a sonic weapon more effective.

Answer (score 0):

An atomic bomb uses the atmosphere to transmit the explosive energy.   Picture those army test explosions where the model towns gets wiped away by wind.  Those bombs wouldn't work well in space without carrying material to transmit the force instead of relying on atmosphere.   (see 1960s project orion rocket program) The problem with a sonic weapon is the energy applied to the atmosphere is going to spread as a wave in all directions and not necessarily stop at the target. So that weapon is probably not realistic but the atmosphere can transmit very destructive energy based on the above reasoning.

Comment: that's a good point about a-bombs -- the shock wave is being transmitted through air and what's more, sort of the same idea, is that tornadoes and high winds can pick up cars, etc.

Comment: Please refrain from answering off-topic questions that are closed.

Comment: It wasn't closed when I answered it